# how to: dynamically load google ajax api into chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-ajax-api

I'm trying to make use of google's ajax apis in a chorme extension's "content script". On a regular html page, I would just do this:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load("language", "1");
</script>
```

But since I'm trying to load the tranlation library dynamically from js code, I've tried:

```
script = document.createElement("script");  
script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi";  
script.type = "text/javascript";  
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); 
google.load('language','1')
```

but the last line throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'load'
```

Funny enough, when i enter the same "`google.load('language','1')`" in chrome's js console, it works as intended...

I've also tried with jquery's `.getScript()` but the same problem persists...

Does anybody have any clue what might be the problem and how it could be solved?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got this working like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = 'http://www.google.com/jsapi';
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("language", "1");
</script>
```

It returned no errors.

Comment: how do you append this block from content-script.js? I am tried the same code from js file. it replaces all the content in the html with `<head><script src="https://www.google.com/uds/?file=elements&amp;v=1&amp;packages=transliteration" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="https://www.google.com/uds/api/elements/1.0/3eced193c1ab3ba305519598439ccaef/transliteration.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://www.google.com/uds/api/elements/1.0/3eced193c1ab3ba305519598439ccaef/transliteration.I.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>`

Answer (score 1):

Content scripts may access only the functions of itself or other content scripts. Since you add google api loader to the document's scripts, you can't call it from your content script.  :)

If you need to load apis into the document's scripts, you can do it by specifying **autoload** parameter : 
"`https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22language%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D%7D`"

http://code.google.com/apis/loader/autoloader-wizard.html